# Is there a way to increment a counter over specific columns in AWK

Tags: awk

I have a input.csv with random numbers and 12 columns in it. I want to ignore every other column except for columnF[6], columnH[8], columnI[9], columnJ[10], columnK[11], columnL[12]. If those columns are not blank, I want to replace the current value with a new value from the counter. I took a crack at writing it, but didn't get the desired output.

```
awk FS=, OFS=, 'NR>1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){if($6=$8=$9=$10=$11=$12!="")gsub("$",$i++)1'}}
```

input.csv

```
input

A,  B,  C,  D,  E,  F,  G,  H,  I,  J,  K,  L
1,  5,  7,  82, 3,  5,  23, 7
3,  7,  3,  23, 56, 90, 35, 8,  29
12, 66, 47, 83, 17, 93, 53, 3,  69, 49, 17
74, 2,  30, 18, 25, 45, 3,  94, 53, 3,  59, 87


desired output

A,  B,  C,  D,  E,  F,  G,  H,  I,  J,  K,  L
1,  5,  7,  82, 3,  1,  23, 2
3,  7,  3,  23, 56, 3,  35, 4,  5
12, 66, 47, 83, 17, 6,  53, 7,  8,  9, 10
74, 2,  30, 18, 25, 11, 3, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
```

Above in the output, columns F,H,I,J,K,L are updated with a counter. The rest of the columns stay the same.

Comment: Please try to rewrite your requirements in a more positive way to make them easier to understand `I want to ignore every column except .... If those columns are not blank...` is at least a double negative if not more! Try something like `For only the columns ... if those columns are populated...`. Also - if your real data doesn't have all those blanks around the `,`s then don't put blanks around the commas in the example in your question so we don't have to figure out how to do that formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't really have all those blanks in your input:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS=","; n=split("6,8,9,10,11,12",f) }
    NR>1 { for (i=1;i<=n;i++) if ($(f[i]) != "") $(f[i]) = ++c }
1' file
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L
1,5,7,82,3,1,23,2
3,7,3,23,56,3,35,4,5
12,66,47,83,17,6,53,7,8,9,10
74,2,30,18,25,11,3,12,13,14,15,16
```

Answer (score 0):

On what OS did you try that?

Please try:

```
awk -F "," 'BEGIN{ OFS=","} NR>1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){if($i!="")$i++;}}1' input
```

1. `BEGIN{ OFS=","}`   Set Output file Separator to ','
2. In the for-loop the value of `$i` is the x-th value of the line

output:

```
A,  B,  C,  D,  E,  F,  G,  H,  I,  J,  K,  L
2,6,8,83,4,6,24,8
4,8,4,24,57,91,36,9,30
13,67,48,84,18,94,54,4,70,50,18
75,3,31,19,26,46,4,95,54,4,60,88
```

If those spaces in the output are needed, you could initialize OFS with `", "`.

EDIT: oops i forgot to add the option to only increment columns 6,8,9,10,11,12

```
awk -F "," 'BEGIN{ a[6]=a[8]=a[9]=a[10]=a[11]=a[12]=1; OFS="," } NR>1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){if($i!="" &&a[i]==1)$i++;}}1' input
```

output:

```
A,  B,  C,  D,  E,  F,  G,  H,  I,  J,  K,  L
1,  5,  7,  82, 3,6,  23,8
3,  7,  3,  23, 56,91, 35,9,30
12, 66, 47, 83, 17,94, 53,4,70,50,18
74, 2,  30, 18, 25,46, 3,95,54,4,60,88
```

Comment: Thanks the solution I had didn't work just an attempt. Is there a way that I can just update columnF[6], columnH[8], columnI[9], columnJ[10], columnK[11], columnL[12] and leave the rest the way they are. I think what I'm saying is updating the rows.Example instead of 2,3,8,9,5 -> 1,2,3,4,5. That's the part I can't figure out

Comment: Added the variant to only increment the given columns